# Separating a string to multiple parts

Tags: c#, .net, string, c++-cli, command-line-interface

If I have a string like `22.3'33'44'` and I want to split the string for each digit in a varaiable like: `a=22.3 b=33 c=44`. How can I do that in C++/CLI or C#?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In c# use .Split

```
String s = "22.3'33'44";
String[] parts = s.Split('\'');
```

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
var strArr = yourstr.Split('\'');
```

Answer (score 1):

this Regular Expression pattern might help: `"\b\d+(\.\d)*\b"`

here's a C# sample:

```
List<Double> _list = new Regex(@"\b\d+(\.\d)*\b").Matches("22.3'33'44'")
.OfType<Match>().Select(t => Double.Parse(t.Value)).ToList();
```